# Is there any way to simplify the path conditions

Tags: pex, z3

For example, in the code below the path condition will be `x>0 && x+1>0`. But since `x>0` implies `x+1>0`, is there any way in z3 or pex API to get only `x>0` and not both.

```
if(x>0)
 if(x+1>0)
   //get path condition.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the Z3 API, you can check whether `A` implies `B` by asserting `A` and `not B` (`Z3_assert_cnstr` function); and checking whether the result is unsatisfiable or not (`Z3_check` function). One simple idea is to keep asserting the path conditions in a Z3 context. Before asserting `A`, you check whether it is implied by the context or not. You can accomplish that using the following piece C of code.

```
Z3_push(ctx); // create a backtracking point
Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, Z3_mk_not(ctx, A));
Z3_lbool r = Z3_check(ctx);
Z3_pop(ctx);  // remove backtracking point and 'not A' from the context
if (r != Z3_L_FALSE) 
   Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, A); // assert A only if it is not implied.
```

Z3 3.2 has a little language for specifying strategies for solving and simplifying expressions.
On this language, you can write:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (> x 0))
(assert (> (+ x 1) 0))
(apply (and-then simplify propagate-bounds))
```

This simple strategy will produce `(>= x 1)` as expected. It is based on much cheaper (but incomplete) methods. 
Another problem is that this functionality is only available in the interactive shell.
The plan is to have these capabilities available in the programmatic API in the next release.